# Differnt Conditional Operator for DynamoDb ScanCondition in .NET

Tags: .net, .net-core, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

How to use different conditional operator in one dynamoDb scan to connect many scan conditiion.
For example: I need to get all entities where Age > 18 && BirthPlace == "Great Britain" || Birthplace == "USA"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordig to the scan [docs for logical evaluation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.LogicalEvaluations), you can use OR and AND operations with parenthesis.  For example:

```
{
    "TableName": "<YOUR TABLE>",
    "FilterExpression": "#age = :age AND (#birthplace = :gb OR #birthplace = :usa)",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {"#birthplace":"BirthPlace","#age":"Age"},
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {":gb": {"S":"Great Birttain"},":usa": {"S":"USA"},":age": {"N":"Age"}}
}
```